# Neo4J - How to create relationship based on an attribute value - if exists or not?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In an existing relationship I want to add an additional one. The new relation should depend on a specific attribute value.

E.g. if an Employee has a value `-1` in `department_id` property, then he should have a relationship: `MEMBER_OF` to `department` table, if he has 1, 2 or 3, then he should have a relation as `HEAD_OF`.

And I think the direction (arrow) for relationships would be opposite to each other  `-[:HEAD_OF]->` or `<-[:MEMBER_OF]-`

One important thing to add is that the value `-1` doesn't exist in the department graph. The dep graph has IDs just from 1 till 8.

In other words, this could be something like: if any employee has an ID which doesn't exist in dep Graph... in this case `-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

After discussing by chat, the queries that best fits the requirements is:

The first query create a `:HEAD_OF` relationship between all employees that have `department_id <> -1` and the respective department.

```
MATCH (emp:Employee) 
WHERE emp.department_id <> -1 
MATCH (dep:Department) 
WHERE dep.id = emp.department_id 
CREATE (emp)-[:HEAD_OF]->(dep)
```

The second query will create a relation `:MEMBER_OF` between employees that have `department_id = -1` and a random department.

```
MATCH (emp:Employee {department_id : -1}) 
MATCH (randomDep:Department) 
WITH collect(emp) as emps, randomDep LIMIT 1 
UNWIND emps as emp 
CREATE (emp)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(randomDep)
```

Comment: Regarding table... you're right. It was just a kind of comparison to try to explain what I mean - in a way.

Comment: I did update my question... an ID with value `-1` doesn't exist in dep Graph. it exists just in emp Graph for some employees. The others have 1, 2, 3, 4 or .... till 8

Comment: @k.vincent Let me know if I understand: if an employee has `department_id = 1`, you want make a relation between this employee and an department with `id = 1`, right?

Comment: No. A department with ID -1 doesn't exist at all in department Graph. So therefore the employee (in employee Graph) with department_id `-1` should have Just a relation `:MEMBER_OF` to one of the departments: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9. in department Graph.

The employees (in employee Graph) who have department_id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 they should have relation: `:HEAD_OF` to the specific department to which they belong (in department Graph)

Comment: @k.vincent the problem here is how to determine what department should be used to make the relation when `employee.department_id = -1`.

Comment: True, but I was thinking about something like to check if `employee.department_id` does exist in department or not. if it returns `null` e.g. Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @k.vincent I don't know if I understand. What should happen when the department does not exists in the graph? Simply ignore it?

Comment: No, if department doesn't exist in the graph, then the employee (in this case has id `-1`) should have relation `:MEMBER_OF`

Comment: @k.vincent yes, but using which department?

Comment: Good Question as `-1` doesn't exist in department. What about just to one of the 9 department? random?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155921/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-k-vincent).